# Cannot get JSP form to read JSON array being returned

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, jsp

I have a strange situation here. I'm working on creating a JSP that will return valid JSON data for my autocomplete feature. I have had this working in Perl for about 5 years but we're looking to move to a Java/JSP solution. A Java developer was helping me with this, and we got this returning valid JSON, much like the original CGI script does.

I'll include the code here. The one oddity - to me - that had to be done was aliasing the columns in quotes within the SQL statement to get it to return the key-value pairs in the proper case, but that did work as far as returning the array.

Basically it's like this:
SQL statement:

```
String query = (String)request.getParameter("term");
if (term.matches("^[\\d\\-\\.]+$")== false) {
query = query.toUpperCase();
}
else {
query = query; 
}
String queryy=("SELECT zip \"zip\", STATEABR \"abbrev\", trim(CITY) \"value\" 
                FROM ZIPCODETBL where "+db_col_to_query+" like '"+query+"%' ORDER BY CITY,
                STATEABR, ZIP ASC");
```

Then it has a Gson object, and that code is like this:

```
    List<Map<String, Object>> listOfMaps = null;
    try {
        QueryRunner queryRunner = new QueryRunner();
        listOfMaps = queryRunner.query(connection, queryy, new MapListHandler());
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't query the database.", se);
    } finally {
        DbUtils.closeQuietly(connection);
    }
    String jsonstr =new Gson().toJson(listOfMaps);
    out.print("json rev str:"+jsonstr);
```

Valid JSON gets returned in the Google Chrome console

e.g.

```
json rev str:[{"zip":"48823","abbrev":"MI","value":"EAST LANSING"},
              {"zip":"48825","abbrev":"MI","value":"EAST LANSING"},
              {"zip":"48826","abbrev":"MI","value":"EAST LANSING"}
             ]
```

This even happens when I key in the city name in the JSP form field. So it does appear to be hitting the DB correctly, just not getting returned in the field via the autocomplete mechanism.
I use JQuery for both the Perl CGI and this JSP. I'm not sure it's not a jQuery issue but I wouldn't think it is. 
I was hoping someone from StackOverflow had experienced something similar or might know what is wrong here.
Please let me know if I have omitted anything that is needed to help troubleshoot this.

Thanks!

Comment: I will add after further investigation a strange oddity occurs between the two items. In the jQuery function, the source file for the JSP (source: "citstatezip_rev.jsp") is getting called, as it returns the JSON data, but the function there is not getting hit when it goes to focus and select on the items.

Comment: Side note: **DO NOT** construct SQL queries by concatenating strings from user input. Read e.g. https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/11/sql-injection-in-java-application.html for more information. (Hint: use `PreparedStatement`)

Comment: Thank you. I got this solved. It turns out I had a written piece with the out.print method identifying the json string and that was inhibiting and breaking the JSON string. Total pilot error. {roblem solved!